# incrementing a variable value inside 1 method triggers off the for loop of another method, any advice welcomed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im building a small random sequence comparitor in order to learn js objects, at the moment I'm having a problem where if I increment the limit variable within my completeMessage() this gets automatically run within the the for loop of my compareSequences() resulting in an infinite loop, could anyone advise me where I may being going wrong?

2 methods in question:

```
compareSequences: function() {                
    var instance = this;
    var i = 0;

    for( i; i <= limit; i++ ) {
        console.log('Limit inside loop:', limit);

        if( stacks.randomSequence[i] != stacks.userSequence[i] ) {
            instance.errorMessage();
            return;
        }                 

        if( i === limit ) {
            instance.completeMessage();
        }

        console.log('Limit now', limit);
    }               
},

completeMessage: function() {
    var instance = this;
    alert('Well done you where right!');
    limit = 5; //currently set as test, changing to ++ results in infinite loop
    instance.selectors.startButton.removeAttr('disabled');
    overallScore++;
    instance.selectors.scoreCounter.html(overallScore);
},
```

Link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FNd79/22/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? limit is a global variable and I assume you know that since limit has no other use in the complete function but I don't see what you would be trying to do with limit++...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `limit` variable is by default defined on the global scope (as a property of the object `window`) changing it's value in one function changes it everywhere.

Be sure to define it as a local of your class using `var`.

Your issue is that you modify your upper bound during the loop, in a way that it increases of one every time you are going to exit the loop.

You need the global value at the time you init the loop, you can just copy it to a local variable at that time:

```
compareSequences: function() {                
  var instance = this;
  var i = 0;
  var max = limit;
  for( i; i <= max; i++ ) {
      ...
  }
  ...
}
```

You could alternatly use the keyword `break` to exit the loop for sure.

```
if( i === limit ) {
  instance.completeMessage();
  break;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Mention of break has made me understand I think what the OP is trying to do and I think a break just after calling the completeMessage is probably what is wanted.

Comment: This is great, can you offer any other advice on my code to make it better? Just coding and learning at the moment